# How to find whether all the data were added or removed in a session?

Tags: java, spring, session

I am using the following `getSession()` method to obtain all the attributes that are being stored in a session. Is there a way to find out whether all the data that were added or removed each time when the user is going through the different pages in the application.

```
  protected HttpServletRequest getRequest() {
        return (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                .getExternalContext().getRequest();
    }
  protected HttpSession getSession() {
        return getRequest().getSession();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [HttpSessionAttributeListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionAttributeListener.html) interface is done for that. Create a class in your web app that implements this interface and override its methods. Then, register your class with the WebListener annotation or directly in your web.xml file.